# When I type a '-' character in vim, it seems that it is printing a carriage return and then 'm'

Tags: vim

It does the same thing when I try to type '+'.

The image below shows what happened when I typed the following in vim:
this\nis\n-----------++++++

But the image below shows what was output on my screen:
[image of my screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tHfbq.png)

Why is this happening and how can I get vim to type a '-'?

Comment: Making some assumptions about your keyboard layout, are you typing `-` on the row above the letters, or `-` on the numeric keypad? Does num-lock affect the results? What do you get if you type (in insert mode) Ctrl-V `-`? You're probably getting an escape sequence; Ctrl-V will let you insert it literally.

Comment: http://ascii-table.com/ansi-escape-sequences-vt-100.php says that EscOm (`^[Om`) is sent by the `-` key on the numeric keypad, depending on whether it's in numeric mode or alternate mode. (I can't reproduce it on my system.) Do you have a Num Lock key? Does pressing it change the mode and cause `-` to behave differently?

Comment: I didn't have a Num Lock key since I thought it would be unnecessary but you have proved me wrong! I just reconfigured my keyboard layout with a Num Lock key and after pressing it, a tack appeared in vim. Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: Something similar that I have also seen is bad keymappings in vim causing similar problems, which you can disprove by running `vim -u NONE` to disable all plugins and your vimrc etc to see if those are causing the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Summarizing from the comments:

http://ascii-table.com/ansi-escape-sequences-vt-100.php says that EscOm (`^[Om`) is sent by the `-` key on the numeric keypad, depending on whether it's in numeric mode or alternate mode. (I can't reproduce it on my system.) If you have a Num Lock key, pressing it should cause the `-` key to send a normal `-` character.